# Recursive dns server with a local forwarded zone and no internet

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a local bind9 server that acts as a small office recursive DNS.

And it also forwards internal names requests to another local dns server:

```
zone "internal.companyname.co.nz" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders {
        192.168.1.x;
        192.168.1.y;
    };
};
```

The problem is though, even though it has `forward only` it still relies on the internet connection to resolve the root dns servers and dns servers for the `.co.nz.` zone.

Is it possible to configure it so that for the specified zone it never ever touched root or other internet zones (so that it did not require an internet connection)?

**Update 2**: It's caused by `dnssec`. So then the question is: can one have a local forwarded zone, `dnssec` enabled and be tolerant for the internet connection loss (for the local zone)?

**Update**: the complete config

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;
    listen-on-v6 { none; };

    recursion yes;
    allow-query { any; };

    allow-transfer { none; };
};


zone "internal.companyname.co.nz" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders {
        192.168.1.x;
        192.168.1.y;
    };
};
```

On the following screenshots those are relevant DNS requests sent to the root and `.nz.` and `.co.nz.` after I've run `dig A internal.companyname.co.nz @localhost` which I assume should not involve any root servers interactions.

[image]

Comment: your question does not make sense as queries to `internal.companyname.co.nz` and all subdomain queries under `internal.companyname.co.nz` would not go to root hints, but query from whatever is .x or .y, assuming x and y actually represent real numbers and assuming you reloaded named.

Comment: @JacobEvans that's what I am currently observing - bind9 emits requests to the root and `.co.nz.` before forwarding the request to forwarders.

Comment: @JacobEvans I have uploaded the traffic that is being captured after I emit `dig A foo.internal.companyname.co.nz @localhost`. Now if I restart bind (to clear cache) and disconnect that machine from the internet - it won't resolve the `internal.companyname.co.nz`.

Comment: Just for kicks, try adding a '.' to the end of 'internal.companyname.co.nz' in the named.conf file.  I've had to do that before with specific BIND versions even though there's no logical reason why it should have been needed.

Comment: @BrandonXavier still the same :-S

Comment: With all due respect, it seems like BIND isn't seeing the forward zone config.  Are you certain you're editing the correct file, and the zone isn't contained in a view or something?  (Maybe try putting in a blatant syntax error in the file and see it it still reloads)

Comment: @BrandonXavier totally - it is this very config used, since if I remove that forward - the requests go to the external DNS (that does not have internal names). I cropped from the screenshot but there are packets being sent to the forwarder server `192.168.1.x` (which I don't think are any relevant to the problem itself). I could reproduce this very behaviour on 2 different machines with bind9 `9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.8`

Comment: I posted the complete config.

Comment: Are the cropped packets going to 192.168.1.x the correct internal queries?  If so, are those servers doing something wacky like forwarding queries back to this server? (or otherwise not responding to them correctly)  Maybe try a 'dig @192.168.1.x someinternaldomain.co.nz' from this server.

Comment: The cropped packets contain the correct and expected request and response. The 192.168.1.x is authoritative non-recursive, it resolves the requested name without problems.

Comment: I've asked the same question in the bind mail list https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2017-November/099256.html

Comment: `dig @192.168.1.x someinternaldomain.co.nz` - this resolves instantly within 1 request-response packet.

Comment: Found it - it's caused by `dnssec`. If I disable it - nothing leaves my network... Wondering if I can still have `dnssec` enabled and a config that is tolerant to the internet connection loss :-S

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the `dnssec`.

The solution would be to slave the forwarded zone instead. Or sign and deploy local `dnssec` if other applications validate the zone content.